# how to declare and use another class's object within a class in c++

Tags: c++, class

I a beginner in programming.
I coded two classes(having constructors with requirement to pass arguments) and want to declare and use one class's object in another class.

I have tried to find the solution to my error on many website, but none of them worked. I also saw a solution to this problem using the '**new**' syntax.
Please suggest some(any) way to sought out  this problem.

A short program similar the one in which I am facing problems is as follows:
(I know this program is stupid but, this is not actual program I am facing problem in. Instead this is a narrowed down version of the part of the program in which I am facing error)

## The error is in Class2.h and main.cpp

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Class2.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   Class2 Class2_Obj;
   Class2_Obj.Class2_Function(); // error: undefined reference to `Class2::Class2_Function

   return 0;
}
```

**Class1.h**

```
#ifndef CLASS1_H_INCLUDED
#define CLASS1_H_INCLUDED

class Class1
{
   private:
   const int c1_Variable;

   public:
   Class1(int);

   // Displays the value of c1_Variable on output screan
   void Class1_Function();
};

#endif // CLASS1_H_INCLUDED
```

**Class1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Class1.h"

Class1::Class1(int receivedInt) : c1_Variable(receivedInt) {}

void Class1::Class1_Function()
{
   cout << c1_Variable;
}
```

**Class2.h**

```
#ifndef CLASS2_H_INCLUDED
#define CLASS2_H_INCLUDED


#include"Class1.h"

class Class2
{
   private:
   Class1 Class1_Obj(4); // 4 is just a random number.
                         //error: expected identifier before numeric constant
                         //error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant

   public:
   // Calls Class1_Function()
   void Class2_Function();
};

#endif // CLASS2_H_INCLUDED
```

**Class2.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Class1.h"
#include "Class2.h"

void Class::Class2_Function()
{
   Class1_Obj.Class1_Function();
}
```

## Here are the links to snapshots of the errors:

Screenshot of Error in Class2.h - https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpK9k.jpg
Screenshot of Error in main.cpp - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDBD7.jpg

> **Please help me out! Thanks in advance for any responses :)**

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Where is the circular include?

Comment: @juanchopanza You're right there isn't one. I've spotted it mistakenly from `main.cpp` not `class1.h`.

Comment: @juanchopanza What is circular include?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that this in-place initialization of non-static data members syntax is invalid:

```
class Class2
{
private:
   Class1 Class1_Obj(4);
   ....
};
```

You can use `{}` instead,

```
class Class2
{
private:
  Class1 Class1_Obj{4};
  ....
};
```

or this form

```
class Class2
{
private:
  Class1 Class1_Obj = Class1(4);
  ....
};
```

Comment: Is this c++11 feature ?

Comment: @AshishNegi It is standard C++, introduced in C++11.

Comment: I think that this is "not" the right way as you just can not give any other value to the `Class1_Obj member of Class2`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a Object Oriented Language. It has classes to structure its data.

To put one class into another, you make `an object of one class` `a member of another class`.

Syntactically, it works like

```
class A {
   int x;
   public:
   A (int x1) : x(x1) {}
};

class B {
   A a; // this is how you do it ..
   public:
   B() : A(4) {}
};

B b; // b is an object which has a member b.a
```

As you can see, `b` is an object of class `B`. It has a member `a` of class `A`.

Comment: OP already has a member of one class inside another one. And this has nothing to do with object orientation.

Comment: @juanchopanza having something in wrong way does not prove that OP has it.